# Search for particular substring in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following list of strings:

```
my_list=["health","nutrition","nature","nutritionist", "nutritionists", "wellness", "food", "drink", "diet"]
```

I would like to assign a label to all the rows which contains one or more of the above words:

```
Search_Col 

heathen
dietcoke
loveguru
drinkwine
lovefood
Pringles
```

then

```
Search_Col     Tag
 
heathen         1   
dietcoke        1
loveguru        0
drinkwine       1
lovefood        1
Pringles        0
```

I have tried first to select rows which contains elements in my_list as follows

```
df.Search_Col.str.contains(my_list)
```

but it does not select rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain values in list by `|` for regex `or` and then convert boolean mask to `0,1` by [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html):

```
df['Tag'] = df.Search_Col.str.contains('|'.join(my_list)).view('i1')
print (df)
  Search_Col  Tag
0    heathen    0
1   dietcoke    1
2   loveguru    0
3  drinkwine    1
4   lovefood    1
5   Pringles    0
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are looking for.  The final answer is different because the first row in your example does not contain any of the entries in the list you provided.  (Perhaps you meant "healthen"?)

```
import pandas as pd
my_list=["health","nutrition","nature","nutritionist", "nutritionists", "wellness", "food", "drink", "diet"] 
df = pd.DataFrame(['heathen','dietcoke','loveguru','drinkwine','lovefood','Pringles'], columns = ['Search_Col'] )

df['Tag'] = df.Search_Col.str.contains('|'.join(my_list)).astype('int')
```

Gives:

```
    Search_Col  Tag
0   heathen     0
1   dietcoke    1
2   loveguru    0
3   drinkwine   1
4   lovefood    1
5   Pringles    0
```